# I can't get AspNetCoreRateLimit to limit API calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, api-design, rate-limiting

I installed AspNetCoreRateLimit and am trying to get it configured properly, but It's not having any effect on the API.

In Startup.cs, in ConfigureServices() I added this

```
#region AspNetCoreRateLimit
            // needed to load configuration from appsettings.json
            services.AddOptions();

            // needed to store rate limit counters and ip rules
            services.AddMemoryCache();

            //load general configuration from appsettings.json
            services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimiting"));

            // inject counter and rules stores
            services.AddSingleton<IIpPolicyStore, MemoryCacheIpPolicyStore>();
            services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();

            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();

            // https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793
            // the IHttpContextAccessor service is not registered by default.
            // the clientId/clientIp resolvers use it.
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            // configuration (resolvers, counter key builders)
            services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>();
#endregion AspNetCoreRateLimit
```

and in Configure() of the same file I put

```
app.UseIpRateLimiting();
```

In appsettings.json I added this section, making sure it's in the object root

```
  "IpRateLimiting": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "RealIpHeader": "X-Real-IP",
    "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    //"IpWhitelist": [ "127.0.0.1", "::1/10", "192.168.0.0/24" ],
    //"EndpointWhitelist": [ "get:/api/license", "*:/api/status" ],
    //"ClientWhitelist": [ "dev-id-1", "dev-id-2" ],
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "5m",
        "Limit": 1
      }
    ]
  }
```

For testing purposes I have it set to 1 call every 5 minutes for the entire API, but I can easily make the same call multiple times in a row with no issues.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar issue but not using IP limiting. It was working before then stopped, but it would've been because I've added services since then.

In your `ConfigureServices` make sure all the registrations are above any other services with the `IHttpContextAccessor` and `IRateLimitConfiguration` are last.

In the Configure method try `app.UseIpRateLimiting();` before everything else.

You can see a startup class here.

https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/ClientRateLimitMiddleware

Comment: You are genius! it worked for me! moving this services before everyother service init. :D why this is not marked as accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try Replace the following lines

```
  // inject counter and rules stores
  services.AddSingleton<IIpPolicyStore, MemoryCacheIpPolicyStore>();
  services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, 
  MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();
```

with

```
services.AddInMemoryRateLimiting();
```

this worked for me in a sample.